# With Aptana, can I have my work-space changes published in 2 places at once (other than the local source)?

Tags: backup

I use Aptana to handle my web development projects and it does an incredible job of it. I especially like the feature that publishes changes on my project's local source to the server that the app really lives on, and vice-versa.

What I'd like to know is whether I can either:

1. have it additionally publish changes to a second server, acting as backup storage.
2. have it additionally publish changes to a locally connected external HDD, acting as backup storage.

Can either of these things be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem:

I'd only used the initial connection wizard to setup the connection between my server and local source, however if you open a project and right click on connections, you'll see the option to add new connection. So this is easy.

You can add as many publishing location (local or remote) as you like with Aptana.